# Gradle Read timed out

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, window, build.gradle

i just did a factory reset on my windows 11. before that my android studio was working perfectly. after the reset when i install android studio and doing all necessary thing like installing java, when i try loading project it keeps telling me `Read timed out` when trying to load gradle. i dont why and i have tried my possible best, but its not working.

i have deleted the .gradle and .idea file, install lower java version